# Can I use the gitlab CI stand-alone?

Tags: maven, ant, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want a script-driven mechanism to provide me with Continuous Integration capabilities, a maven or ant or makefile type capability but completely independent of language and runtime, and portable to any environment.

It's not that I don't like Jenkins and Teamcity and Bamboo, it's that I want something whose build definition is kept with, versioned with and is distributed by developers through their source controlled system.

I want to be able to run this from anywhere, developer workstations, team-city, a docker image - anywhere.

I think that the CI implemented in Gitlab may be able to do this for me. If so, where do I start (documentation, a blog entry?).

If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: The new Jenkinsfile capability from the pipeline plugin to Jenkins now enables you commit your build logic alongisde your source code. This is similar to how GitLab CI works (and other build systems that inspired the idea, like Travis CI). See: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at GitLab's CI Runner. Its a single executable written in GO that runs on all my target environments and processes the gitlab-ci.yml file.

I think this checks all my boxes, but any comments are most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

TeamCity 10 offers a DSL (Kotlin based) that does the same thing and can be used wherever a JVM runs.